# Equivalent of ExpressionEngine switch tag in wordpress/php?

Tags: php, wordpress, expressionengine

In ExpressionEngine while in their version of 'the loop' I can add a tag to any element like this:

```
<li class="{switch='one|two|three|four|five|six'}">
```

The first iteration of the li will have class one, the next is two, and the loop again after six. I'm needing this similar functionality in a wordpress site, but not sure how to accomplish that. Is there a built in wordpress function or will I need to code some sort of function in php?

Currently, using this in attempt at using @Leonard's solution, but the class 'four' is being repeated over and over instead of cycling

```
<?php

$argsGallery = array(
    'post_type' => 'gallery',
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'order'         => 'ASC'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $argsGallery );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>

            <div class="<?php cycle('four|three|five|two|six|four'); ?> columns">
                <div class="thumb">

                    <a class="jackbox" 
                        data-group="images" 
                        data-thumbnail="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" 
                        data-title="Image One" 
                        data-description="#description_1" 
                        href="<?php the_field('image'); ?>"
                    >
                        <div class="jackbox-hover jackbox-hover-black">
                            <p><?php the_field('image_description'); ?> </p>
                        </div>
                        <img 
                            src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" 
                            alt="responsive lightbox" 
                        />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

<?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Hi Brunam, just wondering if you've had a chance to check out that reviewed code I posted and if so, did it work for you?

Comment: Leonard, gonna plug it in today and see and let you know. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No worries! I've used it a bit myself and so far all seems good though that doesn't mean it's perfect. Happy to help if you have any more issues with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this question whilst looking for the exact same thing... top of Google 20mins after you posted it. Crazy... anyway!

I've come up with a function that I've tested (albeit quickly) that you can drop in to your functions.php and it works with a standard Wordpress loop. It may need adapting for some needs but hopefully it's a good start point.

It uses the current_post count from the $wp_query array and works out where it needs to be in the cycle values.

```
function cycle($input, $delimiter = '|', $query = false) {

    if($query == false):
        global $wp_query ;
        $current_post = $wp_query->current_post + 1;
    else:
        $current_post = $query->current_post + 1;
    endif;


    $switches = explode($delimiter, $input);

    $total_switches = count($switches) ;
    $current_set = ceil( $current_post / $total_switches)  ;

    $i = (($current_post - ($current_set * $total_switches)) + $total_switches) - 1 ;

    echo $switches[$i];

}
```

Then you can use it in a STANDARD loop like so:

```
 <?php cycle('first|second|third|fourth'); ?>
```

Or you can custom delimit if needs be:

```
 <?php cycle('first*second*third', '*'); ?>
```

Or if your using it with a CUSTOM wp_query you must use it like this with the query fed in as the third argument:

```
 <?php cycle('first|second|third', '|', $the_query); ?>
```

I'm sure there is a tidier way to feed in that custom query, I'll keep looking and update if/ when I find a way!

Comment: I'm a little lost. Please show me an example output for `<li class="{switch='one|two|three|four|five|six'}">` using this code. Seems that we are talking about different things :)

Comment: Awesome! This should do what I'm looking for, but I'm trying to use it within a custom WP_Query and it just returns the first input option. For example, I set it at 

`<?php cycle('four|three|five|two|six|four'); ?>`

But I only get four repeated in every element.

Comment: @brunam What have to do `$wp_query` with the classes you asked? `The first iteration of the li will have class one, the next is two, and the loop again after six`. What about `<li class="one"></li><li class="two"></li>` like my answer gives? Is not that what you want?

Comment: I'll update my code at top to what I'm currently using... It's not working like it should...

Comment: I think I know how to get round the issue of custom wp_query, give me a few moments and I'll give it a test and update.

@NomikOS I'll post an example for that when I update things.

Comment: The usage for Brunam's code would be:
<?php cycle('four|three|five|two|six|four', '|', $the_query); ?>

Feels like it could be a lot slicker as it'd be nice to use it without having to feed in those extra arguments. If I find a way I'll update things.

Comment: I can't find a way to get the function to automatically work out the query variable if it's custom so feeding it is the only way I can see as being practical. What would also be practical is to remove the delimiter option and hardcode it... that would save an argument when using it in your template!

Comment: Please someone explain to me for what you need `global $wp_query` inside the cycle function? It is a simple iterator over the `four|three|five|two|six|four` string! Why so many complications and DB overhead?

Comment: It's actually pretty straight forward, and one of the most straight forward convenient approaches to the problem! The $wp_query global is an object which I believe only makes a db call when it's created so using it in the function shouldn't create any DB overhead. This var is used because it stores a count of how many items through the loop it is, this saves needing to add a counter to the main wp or making an internal counter in the function (which would need to be global and would only allow for one use of the function per loop).

Comment: Just done a test and can confirm that using `global $wp_query` does not make any extra database calls.

Comment: OK with the overhead issue, You right meanwhile you don't use it to make unnecessary DB calls. But man :) to have a counter just use a simple and nice [static variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) `static $i = 0;`. It's not `global` and makes code very much clean!

Comment: The problem with that is if you want to use the function more then once within a loop it would trigger an increment of the counter causing the outputs to run non-sequentially. Also if you used multiple loops in a template you would have to reset the counter each loop had finished. As this is all handled in the data provided by $wp_query it keeps the process stable and provides the easiest code to implement its usage. I understand `global` isn't in theory good practice, but Wordpress use them a hell of a lot and so this doesn't really spoil it's coding ethics.

Comment: Fair enough. Now I see your point. Indeed just one month ago I have fronted that situation using something like `$i[$depth]++`. I wrapped all code into a class with static methods and members. But, OK, from this point of view your solution make sense so I give you your first +1.8)

Comment: Cheers dude! To be honest before I wrote that today I didn't even know `$wp_query->current_post` acted as a count, before that I was thinking about a `static` approach. That var has made it so much easier to get around potential bugs, without it I think the function would be better off structured as a plugin to do it right.

Comment: @Leonard, thanks for this genius bit of code! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @brunam Cheers, glad it's all working for you. I'm loving having it to use in templates myself. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I know enough WP and I never see something like that. Maybe that's why `ExpressionEngine` is payed (have already built-in solutions like that. In WP you must to do it at hand). Here an idea to make it by your own:

**UPDATE**: @jason-mccreary 's answer I know that I was wrong. I didn't know nothing about `cycles`. But here I have a snippet that seems to work like that:

```
function cycle($chunks)
{   
    if ( ! is_array($array = explode('|', $chunks)))
        return;

    static $i    = 0;
    echo $array[$i ++];
    if ($i >= count($array))
        $i   = 0;
}
?>

<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 9;  ++ $i) : ?>
    <li class="<?php echo cycle('one|two|three|four|five|six'); ?>"></li>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
<li class="one"></li>
<li class="two"></li>
<li class="three"></li>
<li class="four"></li>
<li class="five"></li>
<li class="six"></li>
<li class="one"></li>
<li class="two"></li>
<li class="three"></li>
```

Comment: @brunam Use my **cycle function**. I just tested in your new Update and iterates exactly as you want `<?php cycle('four|three|five|two|six|four'); ?>`. Then change his name to avoid collisions and put it in your theme's `function.php` file and go for a beer right away...

Answer (score 0):

This is known as a *cycle* function. Unfortunately, PHP does not have such a function natively.

You will need to custom write one, either by:

- Creating a function. Here's a [good example](http://baylorrae.com/creating-a-cycle-function-in-php/).
- Directly in your loop with a *counter* and [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php). The following is a contrived example:

  ```
  $cycles = array('one', 'two', 'three');
  for ($i = 0; $i < 9; ++$i) {
    echo $cycles[$i % 3];
  }
  ```